# Description to current location?

Tags: iphone, android-mapview

Is there a way to display some text on the blue dot alike to an annotation? Right now, it only shows "current location" when the user tap on it. I want it to act somewhat like an annotation to display current address. Where there's a title and subtitle property available to use.

I thought of replacing it with my own annotation but can't figure the way to do so.

Please advise.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it by implementing mapView:didSelectAnnotationView: in MKMapView Delegate...

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view{
    if(view.annotation = mapView.userLocation){
        //reverse geocode mapview.userLocation.coordinate to get address
        //then set title
    }
}
```